# Windows 8 graphics/resolution issue on 13" Retina MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, windows-8, macbook-pro-retina

I'm having an issue running Windows 8 on my new 13" Retina MacBook Pro. Installation completed okay, boot screen and Windows logo display fine, but after that the display contents appear to be condensed in the left 1/6th portion of the screen.

I was able to get through the initial setup, as (it appears) that the screen magnifier has been activated. I then managed to get to the Desktop screen (only three tiles on the first column are visible, I had to extrapolate), but I can't seem to open an explorer window.

I'm at a loss at what to do here. It's possible that it's a problem with the graphics driver (Intel HD 4000 in this model), but I'm doubtful that's the case, as several Google searches didn't bring up anything.

Comment: What resolution does Windows think it's running in?  Have you tried updated drivers from Intel.com?

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue, solved it by connecting to an external HDMI projector , installing the boot camp drivers and restarting the machine

Answer (score 1):

Agreed - connecting some type of monitor to the HDMI port caused the video to display correctly on both my external monitor and the Macbook Pro 13 screen. I simply installed the Boot Camp drivers and rebooted as stated, all good.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is still having this issue, and the above *does not* sort it, first do as stated, and install bootcamp drivers, then reboot without hdmi plugged in, login to windows by pressing enter twice, (and typing in any password you set in the previous step in between the Two 'enter's), then use the arrow keys to open the desktop tile (may take some experimenting). Then you can find your mouse pointer by moving it side to side, right click somewhere on the desktop, select screen resolution, use your 'mouse' to move the window (pulling to top bar to the side, bit by bit.. Until you can change the settings in the window, then I selected 1920x1200, click apply, and voila, you now have a whole screen of windows 8 ;)